# UIImageView change image immediately

Tags: ios, uiimageview

In my current implementation, I tap on the view and the image changes only after the whole tap gesture method is completed. However, how can I refresh the view immediately after calling, so that the user sees the new image for a few seconds and continue processing from then on.

Edit: more info.
I want to display the new image for ~ 1 second only. Then, the old image should be displayed.That's the reason why I want the sleep function in. We are aiming at a board game with cards here...

Suggestions anyone?

```
myUIImageViewSubclass.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.jpg"]; 

[myUIImageViewSubclass refresh]; // <- that's what I'm looking for

sleep(1);
//do something else
myUIImageViewSubclass.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oldImage.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display won't update the image until the method returns and there is nothing you can do about that, that's how the display loop works.  If your processing takes long enough to produce a noticeable delay on the UI, you should dispatch that code to another queue.

UI updates have to be done on the main thread, so when you want to change the image back you need to go back to it.

```
myUIImageViewSubclass.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.jpg"]; 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    sleep(1);
    //do other stuff
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        myUIImageViewSubclass.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oldImage.jpg"];
    });  
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it then failed to do something else. Please check the main question because I added some more info there. It works such that the view displays the new image, but I want to go back to the original view after ~1 second. Changing back to the first image fails in the queue.

Comment: Changing the image back needs to be on the main thread, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about those gesture detectors, but you can use `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent` methods in your view controller.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *t = [event touchesForView:_myImageView];
    if([t count] > 0) {
        // Change image here
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *t = [event touchesForView:_myImageView];
    if([t count] > 0) {
        // Or change image here
    }
}
```

Don't use sleep method inside those methods, or there will be delay